# How to continue playing music in background after user swipes away the app?

Tags: android, service, android-service, android-mediaplayer

In Android, I use `Service` and `MediaPlayer` to play music. The music continues playing when I press home button, but stops if I "swipes away" the app.

> How could I continue music playing after swiping away the app?

Comment: http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html. try this.

Comment: Does the service have separate process?

Comment: Yes use binded services, and then make then foreground with a sticky notification

Comment: I have encountered the same problem. I tried using a separate private process for my Service and using a separate thread to start the MediaPlayer to no avail. I also start the Service in the foreground with a notification and the problem persists. Both the Samsung and Google Music Players do not have this problem. If I press the back button to go to the home screen or previous app the MediaPlayer continues to work.

Comment: You probably need to post some code, minimally your `Service`. This always-on stuff is exactly what a Service is designed to do, and the behavior you're describing sounds like you have unintentionally broken the default behavior of Service

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Service.START_STICKY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) :

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    mediaPlayer.start();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

> **Service.START_STICKY** : if this service's process is killed while it is
>   started the system will try to re-create the service.

Here´s a complete example:
https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-Music-in-Background

```
public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "BackgroundSoundService";
    MediaPlayer player;

    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onBind()" );
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.jorgesys_song);
        player.setLooping(true); 
        player.setVolume(100, 100);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service started...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate() , service started...");

    }
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player.start();
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onUnBind()");
        return null;
    }

    public void onStop() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStop()");
    }
    public void onPause() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPause()");
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service stopped...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate() , service stopped...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onLowMemory()");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Android [media player code](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music) uses a [service](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music/blob/master/src/com/android/music/MediaPlaybackService.java) which contains the MediaPlayer object. This allows playback to continue even though an Activity isn't in the foreground.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use foreground service to keep playing music when app closed

```
 private fun createNotification() {
        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_1_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify)
            .setContentTitle(titleSong)
            .setContentText(artist)
            .setLargeIcon(artwork)
            .setSound(null)
            .setShowWhen(false)
            .setColorized(true)
            .setColor(Color.BLACK)
            .setContentIntent(intentPlayer)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_previous, "Previous", pendingPre)
            .addAction(drawable_id, "Play", pendingPlay)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_next, "Next", pendingNext)
            .setDeleteIntent(pendingDelete)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setStyle(
                androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                    .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2)
            )
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .build()
        startForeground(1, notification)
      
    }
```

call above method when app closed